# Types for Dynamic Programming

Tags: typescript, dynamic-programming, typescript-typings

```
type someObj = {
    a: number,
    b: Array<string>,
    c: { d: string },
    e: {
        f: string,
        g: Array<{
            h: string,
            i: Array<number>
        }>
    },
    j: {
        k: string,
        l: Array<string>
    },
    m: Array<Array<string>>
};

type someGeneric<T /* can be primitive, array or object */> = ???;
// Expected Result


type someObjGenericResult = {
    b: (item: string) => void,
    e: {
        g: (item: { h: string, i: Array<number> }) => {
            i: (item: number) => void
        }
    },
    j: { l: (item: string) => void },
    m: (item: Array<string>) => (item: string) => void 
};
```

So i was looking to code a generic that would take in an any value and execute a function on each array that may be in the object(no matter how nested it is) 
and have following properties

=> exclude all primitive(like someObj.a)

=> exclude object that do not have a prop that has array as type(like someObj.c)

=> but include object which have an array as a prop(like someObj.j).

=> user currying for Arrays that have nested arrays(like someObj.m).

Comment: Good plan. What's your question?

Comment: I am not sure hot to code the generic.

Comment: I was looking for some recursive calls in the generic itself but typescript makes it very difficult.

Comment: I think your output `someObjGenericResult` type has at least one typo... the type `{i: (item: string) => void}` should be `{i: (item: number) => void}` unless I'm very much mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATING DUE TO CHANGED QUESTION

If you're just looking at how to do the typing (and not the runtime code which turns an instance of `someObj` into an instance of `someObjGenericResult`) I *think* the following will work:

```
// HasNestedArrays<T> outputs unknown (meaning true) or never (meaning false)
// depending on whether T is an array or an object with at least one
// property that HasNestedArrays itself.  This is a recursive definition.
// HasNestedArrays<{a: {b: {c: string[]}}}> should return unknown,
// HasNestedArrays<{a: {b: {c: string}}}> should return never.
type HasNestedArrays<T> = T extends Array<any> ? unknown :
  T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: HasNestedArrays<T[K]> }[keyof T] : never;

// PickHasNestedArrays<T> takes an object type T and removes any properties
// that do not pass the HasNestedArrays test. 
// PickHasNestedArrays<{a: string, b: string[], c: {d: string[]}}> should return
// {b: string[], c: {d: string[]}}.
type PickHasNestedArrays<T extends object> = Pick<T,
  { [K in keyof T]: unknown extends HasNestedArrays<T[K]> ? K : never }[keyof T]
>

// SomeGeneric<T> is the type you want: 
// If T is an array like U[], return a function (item: U) => SomeGeneric<U>.
// If T is an object, strip all the non-array-containing properties out
// (via PickHasNestedArrays<T>) and assign the stripped object to V.
// If V is an empty object, then return void. 
// Otherwise, return a new object whose properties have the same keys K from V
// but whose values are SomeGeneric<V[K]>.
type SomeGeneric<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ?
  (item: U) => SomeGeneric<U> :
  T extends object ? (
    PickHasNestedArrays<T> extends infer V ? (
      {} extends V ? void : { [K in keyof V]: SomeGeneric<V[K]> }
    ) : never
  ) : void;

type someObjGenericResult = SomeGeneric<someObj>;
```

Note that in TypeScript, [`unknown`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#new-unknown-top-type) is the so-called [top type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_type) which includes all values... it's basically the "true" of types.  And [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never) is the so-called [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type) which includes no values... it's basically the "false" of types.  When I do boolean-like type operations I tend to output `unknown`/`never` for `true`/`false` because it sometimes makes subsequent operations easier.

The `HasNestedArrays<T>` and `PickHasNestedArrays<T>` types are used to strip out all the properties of `T` you don't care about.  And the `SomeGeneric<T>` is the type function you asked for.  I've explained *what* they do in the comments above, but *how they work* requires understanding [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types), [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), and [lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types).  If you understand all the notation and need more specifics about what is going on in some case, I can elaborate.

I'm not sure if the `SomeGeneric<T>` is *exactly* what you actually want, since there are edge cases like `SomeGeneric<number>`, `SomeGeneric<{a: number}>`, etc.  I'm pretty sure the above definition spits out `void` for most edge cases.

Anyway, I hope this helps.  Good luck!

Comment: I am sorry @jcalz i made a hard problem even harder. So `Array<{a: Array<string>, b: Array<number>}>` should return `(item: {a: Array<string>, b: Array<number>}) => { a: (item: string) => void, b: (item: number) => void }` and currying should be done in case of `someObj.m` as in the edit. If You cold just take a look. Im sorry its been late at night.

Comment: Could you edit your question and add any refinements there instead of in a comment just to me?  I don't want to dissuade others from answering.

Comment: I have actually `someObj.g` now returns appropriate value

Comment: Updated due to new question... does this actually output what you want?  I don't want to explain something if I have to change it again

Comment: Oculd you please explain what the following two lines accomplish `PickHasNestedArrays<T> extends infer V ? (
      {} extends V ? void : { [K in keyof V]: SomeGeneric<V[K]> }` and `[K in keyof T]: unknown extends HasNestedArrays<T[K]> ? K : never`

Comment: Updated again.  Hoping the output is actually what you want.  Also hope that you will at least vote the answer up after all this 

Comment: Good Lord. Thank you for all your effort. God Bless.

Comment: this used to work fine but i recently updated to typescript version 3.4, it now give me a error `Type alias 'HasNestedArrays' circularly references itself`

Comment: Well i updated the code and replaced `never` with `void` for the primitive branch in `HasNestedArrays` and all of a sudden the error was gone, it would be really helpful if you could explain why such a thing happened, thanks.

Comment: I changed `type HasNestedArrays<T> = T extends Array<any> ? unknown :
  T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: HasNestedArrays<T[K]> }[keyof T] : never;` to `type HasNestedArrays<T> = T extends Array<any> ? unknown :
  T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: HasNestedArrays<T[K]> }[keyof T] : void;` and all of a sudden the error was gone.

Comment: I just checked with TS3.5 and I can't reproduce the error.  I think TS3.4 was being very aggressive with evaluating types and they have fixed it in TS3.5... but of course that means the above code is probably not officially supportable (see [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980)).  One could always unroll the circular type into a list of non-circular types if need be, as in:

Comment: [this code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAEghgZwHIQcCATAggJx3EBAHgBUA+KAXihKggA90A7DBKXfEIuJkCgfigBXJgGsmAewDuTKAC4adRhBZsJAIwBWEAMbAoggN5QA2gGkoAS1miIICQDMaAXQXxkqdNjwEEARlJzZwoAXxNbeycSZ3koJggANwgcAG4AKFBIWEQUNEwOXwDyKkUGZlZ2Hy4ePgNhMUkZWNoylQqNbT0643MrGztHFzccz3yqhAAmQLNgqDCIwejY+KTUjPBod1yvAsIp4uoW5VVKzm5eAXrxaVkFI-K1LV19I1MLaygFqNdsjzzvTgIADM01m8wG32WiWS6UymxG-12wNIFEOSgepwI51qghE1yad3RbUenReUB6736kSGv22Y0BABZQaFwhCXFDVrCNrTRgDfEyDqVjhVdtjLnjGrchRiOs9um8+p82dFhn8duMAKzMuas6lLBQrGHrLJbXlIrWC+7EzHVC51CU3ZpEk6yrqvXofL4002I8YADW14L1MQN0LWcJ5vsBAcFhpwUAA9AmoOo4JYADZQCRCYBAA)